# Unit testing a function that produces csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unit-testing, pytest

I have a function that produces csv files.
These files are written based on the contents of dataframes.

I would like to write unit tests for this function.

I suppose I can read a csv file with the correct intended values into a dataframe and then make an assert.

However some of the values of these dataframes are not *exactly* the same. For example they can be numbers like 8.00 and 7.999999

My question is how can I write assertions comparing two dataframes that check their approximate equality?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pandas, you can use the pandas.testing module (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html#pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [8.00], 'B': [7.999999]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [8.01], 'B': [7.999998]})

tolerance = 0.01

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_less_precise=True, atol=tolerance)
```

Comment: this does not use pytest , does it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pytest you can do the following

```
relative_tolerance = 0.000001
x = 7.999999
y = 8.0
assert x == pytest.approx(y, relative_tolerance)
```

Comment: does it work for dataframes?

Comment: can you share some code?, might be easier to use pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal in this case... there is also relative_tolerance (rtol) support

Answer (score 0):

Pythons `unittest` framework has a method that may be helpful [`assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual)